# How can I forward Protobuf data from Flink to Kafka and stdout?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to add some codes here and stdout the protobuf data from Flink.

I am using Flink's Apache Kafka Connector in order to connect Flink to Kafka.

This is my Flink's code.

```scala
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").
val producer = FlinkKafkaProducer011(topic, new myProtobufSchema, props)
env.addSink(producer)
env.execute("To Kafka")
```

Here is my Kafka's code.

```scala
  val props: Properties = {
    val p = new Properties()
    p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "protobuf-application")
    p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
    p
  }

  val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
  // TODO: implement here to stdout 

  val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props)
  streams.start()

  sys.ShutdownHookThread {
     streams.close(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the [`StreamsBuilder`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html) to consume from a topic

```
val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
    .stream(topic)
    .print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

Comment: I got this error.
`: error: missing parameter type
      .foreach((k, v) => {
                ^
error: missing parameter type
      .foreach((k, v) => {
`

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#print-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed-

Comment: Maybe you need to import some implicits? Check out the docs about the Scala API: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstreams-dsl-for-scala